# Is it safer or unnecessary to encrypt a JWT with one key agreed upon by all programers of a project?

Tags: php, security, encryption, laravel-5, jwt

I am currently working in a e-commerce project in which i am designing the Server-Side of an API (in PHP on Laravel 5.5) while my two colleagues are designing the Android and Ios apps which will get all their data from my side.

The communication of sensitive and non-sensitive data will be done entirely via this API, but, being all of us relatively inexperienced, we have trouble in deciding whether it is safe or even necessary to encrypt all our exchanges with a key hard-coded and agreed upon during development, while using JWT.

I have looked far and wide for a clear consensus, but the process is already slightly confusing, and the expert-opinions seems to be divergent on points so refined that the consequences escape me completely.

Can anyone "security-savy" help us with the following questions ?

1) is using JWT safe on its own (provided we use 'common sense') ? i.e. Is it a respected standard among professionals ?

2) is using JWT considered 'good practice' for an app that will deal with payment information ?

3) is encrypting the JWT on the sender's side and decrypting on the recipient side safer ? Or are we just adding an extra layer here but leaving a door wide open there ?

4) Reading the Laravel 5.5 docs, i see that they offer the Passport plugin, Is this reliable to use for beginners ?

5) Most importantly, is there a source of reliable information concerning communication security, in the same way w3c is safekeeping the 'best practices' ?

Please feel free to correct the question itself.
Thank you.

Comment: There is no *encrypting* in JWT. Dont put sensitive stuff in the payload, JWT is simply to sign a claim/auth.

Comment: Could i put sensitive stuff if i encrypted it ?

Comment: Yeah, but then you need to share the decryption key with every device.

Comment: You don't need to encrypt the API data nor put it all in JWT's payload (dont forget it adds 33% in size, so RSA "hello world" could turn into a 352+ bytes payload after base64) just let SSL do the encryption, you just need to make sure endpoints are not accessible to non authenticated users, which JWT on their own, without encrypted data will do. About the known secret, it does not matter they just have to be the same, if you change the secret it will simply log everyone out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) is using JWT safe on its own (provided we use 'common sense') ? i.e. Is it a respected standard among professionals ?

[You should avoid JWT](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/03/jwt-json-web-tokens-is-bad-standard-that-everyone-should-avoid). It's possible to use it securely, but you'll end up going 60% of the way towards reinventing [PASETO](https://paseto.io), so you might as well use PASETO instead.

> 2) is using JWT considered 'good practice' for an app that will deal with payment information ?

You definitely want your PCI-DSS auditor to inspect your JWT code, if you strictly *must* use JWT.

If you want a JWT library that's already been audited to make your PCI-DSS compliance smoother, [Luís Cobucci's JWT library](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt) is a good choice. (The report is [publicly accessible](https://paragonie.com/audit/UGCwpFmaIkQ085l7).)

> 3) is encrypting the JWT on the sender's side and decrypting on the recipient side safer ? Or are we just adding an extra layer here but leaving a door wide open there ?

If you mean over HTTPS, absolutely, yes.

Otherwise, don't roll your own crypto.

> 4) Reading the Laravel 5.5 docs, i see that they offer the Passport plugin, Is this reliable to use for beginners ?

Yes.

> 5) Most importantly, is there a source of reliable information concerning communication security, in the same way w3c is safekeeping the 'best practices' ?

There is an up-to-date (as of 2018) [guide to PHP security](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/12/2018-guide-building-secure-php-software) that delves into a lot of cryptographic security topics as well.

Comment: While I had lost hope of ever seeing this answered, Scott came through methodically. Thank you very much for that